# MySQL :The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, mysql

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Healthcare.docInterface.WebForm3" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
Line 4:  <%@ Import Namespace="Healthcare.dbcon" %>
Line 5:  <%@ Import Namespace= "System.Data" %>
```

The code when written in code-behind works fine.

How do I use `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` in the .aspx file itself?

Comment: Why do you have the line `CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs"` when you are writing the code here ?

Comment: I'm generating a dynamic webpage: <table>  <% //some code%> <tr><td> <%//some code%> </td> </tr> <% //come code >  </table>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySql.Data.MySqlClient dll must be exist in /bin/ directory.

Comment: Some errors vanished but a pair of them remained. Still cannot compile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the assembly from GAC if the dll is not in your bin folder - by adding something like

```
<add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
```

to your web.config in compilation/assemblies section